# Объединить три таблицы в MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

Привет всем! У меня есть три таблицы.

table_1 - id, title

table_2 - id, title

table_3 - id, id_table_1, id_table_2

В 3 таблице хранится связь между первой и второй таблицы. У первой таблицы может быть множество во второй? Как запросом совместить данные из table_1 с table_2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем в 3ей таблице id? можно же просто индекс по 2м полям создать.

Если надо список вывести то так:

```
SELECT table_1.* ,table_2.title FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_3 ON table_1.id = table_3.id_table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_2.id = table_3.id_table_2
```

Если надо к примеру через запятую вывести то

```
SELECT table_1.*, group_concat(table_2.title) as title_list FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_3 ON table_1.id = table_3.id_table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_2.id = table_3.id_table_2
```

Да и возможно еще и сгруппировать по table_1.id пишу не проверяя.